# Change date field value while submitting the form in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I have a form

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(BaseRegistrationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name of the Entrepreneur', max_length=120)
    ename = forms.CharField(label='Name of the Enterprise', max_length=120)
    sector = forms.CharField(label='Industry Sector', max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=zip(SECTOR_CHOICES, SECTOR_CHOICES)))
    subsector = forms.CharField(label='Sub-sector', max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=zip(SUBSECTOR_CHOICES, SUBSECTOR_CHOICES)))
    address1 = forms.CharField(label='Address Line 1', max_length=100)
    address2 = forms.CharField(label='Address Line 2', max_length=100, required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(label='City/Town', max_length=50)
    state = forms.CharField(label='State', max_length=50)
    country = forms.CharField(label='Country', max_length=50)
    postal_code = forms.CharField(label='Pin Code', max_length=10, required=False)
    estd = forms.DateField(label='Establishment Details')
    contact = forms.IntegerField(label='Contact Number')
```

For the `DateField` variable I have written javascript

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#id_estd').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

In the `estd` field it shows mm/yy (ex: 02/2014)

While submitting the form I should submit the value like mm/dd/yy. So How can I change the value while submitting the form??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No use with the javascript or something else. There is a snippet in django use it.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1688/

Save the snippet code in some file called `widgets.py` and import the class name in your `forms.py` file and follow the below code:

```
import datetime
class myForm(forms.Form):
    # ...
    date = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
        widget=MonthYearWidget(years=xrange(1990,datetime.date.today().year+1))
    )
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a better idea to use one format for humans, and another alternate one for processing. JQuery UI Datepicker allows an alternate field to be populated with a different format: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field

Basically rename your existing datepicker field, add a hidden input named `estd` with an id `id_estd` (default name and id Django would assign) and add the following lines while initializing your datepicker:

```
altField: "#id_estd",
altFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
```

Comment: I can't rename the existing datepicker filed id or name whatever. In template I was using as {{ form }} to display the form

Answer (score 0):

Why use javascript to change the value? Just set the format in django.

```
class MyForm(Form):  

    # the default format is %Y-%m-%d  
    estd = forms.DateField(  
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%m/%Y")
    )
```

Docs for the `DateInput` widget; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput

Date/Time input format settings are detailed here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: On giving the widget doesn't make sense. Still it is taking default format and raising error.

Comment: Have you got the default django date/time formats defined? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#date-input-formats